# Use gearman from PHP application without installing PHP extension

Tags: php, pecl, gearman, worker

I'm interested in using a Gearman server to distribute long-running jobs in my PHP application. Unfortunately I don't have direct access to my application servers and I can't install any PECL extensions.

Is there a pure PHP client library out there I can use?

Comment: You cannot install the extension, but you can install a gearman server?

Comment: Yes. The gearman server will run on a different machine that I do have control over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the obvious?

> **Net_Gearman (PHP)**
>
> A pure PHP API that can be found as Net_Gearman on PEAR.
>
> - [PHP module on PEAR](http://pear.php.net/package/Net_Gearman/)

Quoted from: http://gearman.org/index.php?id=download#php

Comment: forgive me if this is a stupid question but just to clarify - if I can't change my PHP installation and I don't libgearman installed on my application servers, I could use Net_Gearman to communicate with my Gearman server?

Comment: Yes, that's what that library is for.